# Converting random effect expression from SAS to R lmer syntax

Tags: r, sas, mixed-models

Random effects of my mixed models formula in `SAS proc mixed` syntax looks like this:

```
 random intercept color size
/type = vc subject = group  solution;
```

I converted it to `R lmer syntax` as follows:

```
((1|group) + (0 + color|group)) + ((1|group) + (0 + size|group))
```

Is it correct?
Can I represent `sas` random effects formula as follows:

```
(1|group) + (0 + color|group)) + (0 + size|group) ?
```

Or is it a wrong implementation in `R`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the SAS syntax, but a quick look at the SAS documentation for the PROC MIXED arguments [SUBJECT =](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_mixed_syntax13.htm&locale=en#statug.mixed.randomstmt_subject) and [TYPE](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_mixed_syntax14.htm&locale=en#statug.mixed.randomstmt_type_vc) gives the following info:

> identifies the subjects in your mixed model. Complete independence is assumed across subjects; thus, for the RANDOM statement, the SUBJECT= option produces a block-diagonal structure in with identical blocks. The matrix is modified to accommodate this block diagonality. **In fact, specifying a subject effect is equivalent to nesting all other effects in the RANDOM statement within the subject effect.**

and

> specifies standard variance components and is the default structure for both the RANDOM and REPEATED statements. **In the RANDOM statement, a distinct variance component is assigned to each effect**

Using table 2 (page 7) in the [`lme4` vignete](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) for fitting mixed effect models, we are looking for the following statement

```
library(lme4)
fit <- (g)lmer(outcome ~ fixed_effects + (1|subject/color) + (1|subject/size), data = data)
```

It has been a while, so I don't remember if a parenthesis works out in the random effects such that it can be reduced to `(1|subject/(color + size))`. This states that "color and size are random intercepts, nested with subject".

Please note that I filled in the entire call. Here one would have to change `outcome`, `fixed_effects` and `data` to suite your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But `type = vc` in `SAS` does not allow the random intercept and slope to be correlated. To specify an uncorrelated slope and intercept in `lmer R`, one may either use double-bar notation, `(x || g)`, or equivalently use multiple random-effects terms, `x + (1 | g) + (0 + x | g)`. That's why I chose double-bar notation. Is it incorrect?

Comment: From your question and the SAS documentation, I can't see that your model includes a random slope. It does state that they are "nested" and "uncorrelated". But it is not clearly describing a random slope. If you are having a random slope, and this is to be uncorrelated, the double bar notation is indeed correct. :-)

Comment: I ran the model in SAS and R (with different random effects structure). When setting the random effects as `(1|subject/color) + (1|subject/size)`, the estimates didn't coincide with the SAS output at all. There was a complete coincidence when I defined the random effects as `(1|subject) + (0 + color|subject)) + (0 + size|subject)`. But I thought it would be more correct to set the formula as `(color||subject)+(size||subject)`...

Comment: It sounds like there is a disparity between definitions in commonly referenced articles and the SAS documentation, or more likely I'm just misunderstanding what the documentation is stating. From the documentation and design description I would expect `(1|subject/(color + size))` to be conceptually the same. This would be giving a block design for the random effect matrix as we expect. Observations between groups would be uncorrelated. Slight deviation of estimates might come from the model formulation (`lme4` uses `SVD` decomposition for optimization purposes), but again. I'm not a SAS user.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Oliver! Do you know how it is possible to interpret such a formula (`(1|subject) + (0 + color|subject) + (0 + size|subject)`)? Сurrently it gives me fully identical coefficients to SAS, while other RE structures give completely different coefficients.

Comment: This would be similar to `((color + size) || subject)` "in concept" (eg. I'm not sure if the parenthesis works as expected). So it is a model with a random slope and intercept, but there are no parameters for the correlation between intercept and slope. Eg: Color and size are each random slope parameters, nested in subject. This should give you an interchanging-diagonal variance structure repeating itself every 3'rd element, if I'm not completely misremembering.